# Get selected text from prime-ng drop down

Tags: angular, primeng

I have the following drop down from which i am trying to get the selected options' text.

```
<p-dropdown 
  [(ngModel)]="benefit.investmentStrategy.defaultOptionId" 
  [options]="defaultInvestmentStrategyArray" placeholder="Select" 
  (ngModelChange)="onCheckForUpdate($event)">
</p-dropdown>
```

defaultInvestmentStrategyArray looks like this

```
[
      {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "Lifestage – Balanced"
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "label": "Lifestage – Passive"
      },
      {
        "value": 2,
        "label": "Lifestage – Specialist"
      }
]

 onCheckForUpdate(changes: any) {
    console.log(changes.target.options[changes.target.options.selectedIndex].text);
 }
```

How can I get the selected options text? Currently I get an undefined error

Comment: Show `defaultInvestmentStrategyArray`

Comment: @AdritaSharma I have updated question to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
onCheckForUpdate(evt: any) {
   console.log(this.defaultInvestmentStrategyArray.find(x => x.value == evt).label);
 }
```